How to avoid side effects when copying a text from a web page?
I often copy texts from a web page. I want to copy and paste what I see. However, when I copy the text, it has some annoying side effects. I use Chrome and Edge on Win 10.
Case 1
We have some web URLs in IP format, like http://192.168.0.1. It displays 192.168.0.1 in the address bar of the browser. After I select and copy 192.168.0.1, it becomes http://192.168.0.1 when I paste it. If I select and copy 92.168.0.1, it's just 92.168.0.1 on paste.
Case 2
There is a file path on the page. It has a hyperlink to the page of the file content. When I select the file path, sometimes it directly jumps to the content page before I can copy. After inspecting the elements by pressing F12, I find the item has registered onclick. I guess my selecting the text invokes onclick somehow.
Case 3
There is a text on the page. I select the text from the last character to the first. Unless I very carefully do not move the mouse pointer beyond the first character, there is always a leading tab copied. I inspect the element of this text. It's a <tr><td><a>foo</a></td></tr>. There is no tab before foo.
In all these cases, I just want to copy the ip, the file path, and the text displayed as is. How can I not copy or automatically strip the leading http:// and the leading tab? How can I not invoke the onclick?  The closest answer is How to strip leading tabs and/or leading spaces when copying data to clipboard?. But I prefer a solution without 3rd party tools. Are there some hotkeys?

Case 1: That occurs because the web link header is hidden by default if it's not shown in the address bar, so copying a web address is by default going to copy the http:// | https:// | ftp:// | etc. Case 2: Have you tried positioning the cursor/pointer slightly more to the left of the beginning of the link? What about highlighting the text starting at the end and going forward? Case 3: Does that happen on all webpages across different sites? If so, are you pasting into a text editor (e.g. Notepad, VS Code, etc.) or other program (e g. word processor, PDF editor, etc.)?

Can you not use "Save Page" and then pull the content you want from the exported file(s)?

Under Linux I simply copy and paste the text into a VI console browser and this does not take the markup with it.  (You may want to amend your post to advise your browser and OS)

@JW0914 Thanks for your help. Case 1 can be solved by selecting Always show full URLs in Chrome. Your suggestion for Case 2 is a good solution. It does not jump to the new page if the pointer is not over the text when the mouse click is released. For Case 3, after some tests I think it happens only on a specific site (Gerrit in my case). The paste behavior is the same on different editors (VS Code, notepad and our Instant Message tool). Could you please write your comments as an answer so that I can accept it? Your suggestions give me clear solutions to avoid the side effects.

This is a silly method but it works reasonably as an alternative. You can use Microsoft PowerToys, which offers a Win+Shift+T keyboard shortcut, triggering a Snipping Tool–style interface, where all text in the selected area is automatically copied to the clipboard (via optical character recognition).
It’s quite reliable, though not as reliable as Microsoft’s built-in text recognition from Snipping Tool itself (though this is only on Windows 11), which requires some extra clicks to get from the image snippet to the text.
I find this method is a good backup if I have no specific method for a given situation.
